# При формировании массива полученных с сервера объектов падает ошибка

Tags: reactjs, get

Я отправил на сервер запрос профиля `people[index]` и получил объект. В этом объекте есть массив `films` с api-шками (ссылками) на фильмы. Я получил этот массив и через `for each` отправил эти api на сервер. В процессе формируется нужный мне массив фильмов(объектов), но при добавлении последнего объекта падает ошибка: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.films.push is not a function or its return value is not iterable`. Надеюсь, объяснил понятно, код прилагается)

```
/////////api
export const profileAPI = {
  getProfile(id) {
    return axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${id}`);
  },
  getFilm(api) {
    return axios.get(api);
  },
};

/////////reducer
let initialState = {
  profileData: null,
  films: [],
};
const profileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profileData: action.profile,
      };
    case SET_FILM:
      return {
        ...state,
        films: [...state.films.push(action.film)], //зыесь падает ошибка
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

//action-creators
export const setProfile = (profile) => ({ type: SET_PROFILE, profile });
export const setFilm = (film) => ({ type: SET_FILM, film });

//Tunk-creators
export const getProfile = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    profileAPI.getProfile(id).then((response) => {
      dispatch(setProfile(response.data));
    });
  };
};
export const getFilm = (api) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    debugger;
    profileAPI.getFilm(api).then((response) => {
      dispatch(setFilm(response.data));
    });
  };
};

export default profileReducer;

////////component
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.profileData) {
      this.props.profileData.films.forEach((item) => {   //здесь я перебираю массив ссылок на фильмы
        this.props.getFilm(item);   //а здесь отправляю ссылки на сервер
      });
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.profileData !== this.props.profileData) {
      if (this.props.profileData) {
        let films = this.props.profileData.films;
        films.forEach((item) => {   //здесь я перебираю массив ссылок на фильмы
            this.props.getFilm(item);   //а здесь отправляю ссылки на сервер
        });
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (!profileData) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className={s.person}>
        //реализация UI
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне дали ответ на мой вопрос. Нужно `[...state.films.push(action.film)]` поменять на `state.films.concat(action.film)`.